# javascript set all values in array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays

Two part question about similar problems. I've got 2 different arrays,

**array 1:**

```
 array1 = [{
     name : "users",
     checked : true
   }, {
     name : "active users",
     checked : false
   }, {
     name : "completions",
     checked : false
   }]
```

I would like to know if there is an easy way to set all the checked values to true at once. I know this is possible with a for loop:

```
  for (var i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++) {
    array[i].checked = false
  }
```

Even though this is not a lot of code i'm just curious if there is a way to do this without iterating over every object in the array. (not sure if this is even possible or whether this makes any difference whatsoever, so if please correct me if i am wrong about any of this).

**array 2:**

```
array2 = [{
     value1 : false,
     value2 : true,
     value3 : false,
     value4 : false, 
     value5 : false,   
   }]
```

Is it possible to simply set all the values to true or false at once (again i can use a for loop, but would prefer not to)

(i'm using angular and lodash, but haven't been able to find a 'lodash' or 'angular' solution, but any solution will do)

Comment: array2 only has 1 element: an object with five properties. If it were an array of values or an array of properties, and if using ES6 is okay, then you could use [Array.prototype.fill()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can't do this without looping over the elements, however there are functional abstractions you can use instead of `for`:

For array 1, you can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Browser_compatability)

```
array1.map(function(x) { 
  x.checked = true; 
  return x
});
```

Or using [_.map](https://lodash.com/docs#map) from lodash:

```
_.map(array1, function(x) { 
  x.checked = true; 
  return x
});
```

For array 2 you can use [_.mapValues](https://lodash.com/docs#mapValues) from lodash.

```
_.mapValues(array2[0], function() {
  return true;
});
```

You can see that lodash implements `_.map` using `while` at https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/a1b15df6489f47498edda244552c9804e046a45d/lodash.js#L3125

Comment: @RayonDabre yes, there is no escape

Comment: I believe .forEach is more suitable in this scenario. Unless there is a case for creating a new array of objects, which .map effectively does.

I know it's an old thread, but someone might find my contribution useful

Comment: can i use map with plain objects ??

Answer (score 25):

You can use es6 fat arrow and make one liner but still it involves iteration .

```
array1.map(a=>a.checked=true);
```

```js
array1 = [{
     name : "users",
     checked : true
   }, {
     name : "active users",
     checked : false
   }, {
     name : "completions",
     checked : false
   }]
   array1.map(a=>a.checked=true);
   console.log(array1);
```

Comment: Using `.map()` without using its return value [is an anti-pattern](https://thenewtoys.dev/blog/2021/04/17/misusing-map/). Simply use [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) in this case.

Answer (score 10):

> Even though this is not a lot of code i'm just curious if there is a way to do this without iterating over every object in the array. (not sure if this is even possible or whether this makes any difference whatsoever, so if please correct me if i am wrong about any of this).
>
> Is it possible to simply set all the values to true or false at once
>   (again i can use a for loop, but would prefer not to)

No ! You can't visit **all towns** without visiting each of them. 
There are shortcuts with jQuery like `$.each` and lodash like `_.map` but it's just a function that's doing what you would do with the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to set the value of each object in an array without iterating (looping) through the array as you mentioned in your question.