# How to set all the values of a given property in an array at once

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this code

```
car = {
    "car_id": "325SDGSD-GSH4GRWW-DH534R",
    "Name": "suzuki",
    "desc": "compact machine to get your from point A to B",
    "engineSerial": "305-6467-3674",
    "Country": "Netherlands",
    "Province": "George",
    "City": "Charlie",
    "branch_timings": {
        "Monday": {
            "doorsOpen": true,
            "timings": [
                { "timeOpen": "00:01", "timeClose": "01:00" },
                { "timeOpen": "12:00", "timeClose": "00:00" }
            ]
        },
        "Tuesday": {
            "doorsOpen": true,
            "timings": [
                { "timeOpen": "00:01", "timeClose": "01:00" },
                { "timeOpen": "12:00", "timeClose": "00:00" }
            ]
        },
        "Wednesday": {
            "doorsOpen": true,
            "timings": [
                { "timeOpen": "00:01", "timeClose": "01:00" },
                { "timeOpen": "12:00", "timeClose": "00:00" }
            ]
        },
        "Thursday": {
            "doorsOpen": true,
            "timings": [
                { "timeOpen": "00:01", "timeClose": "01:00" },
                { "timeOpen": "12:00", "timeClose": "00:00" }
            ]
        },
        "Friday": {
            "doorsOpen": true,
            "timings": [
                { "timeOpen": "00:01", "timeClose": "01:00" },
                { "timeOpen": "12:00", "timeClose": "00:00" }
            ]
        },
        "Saturday": {
            "doorsOpen": true,
            "timings": [
                { "timeOpen": "00:01", "timeClose": "01:00" },
                { "timeOpen": "12:00", "timeClose": "00:00" }
            ]
        },
        "Sunday": {
            "doorsOpen": true,
            "timings": [
                { "timeOpen": "00:01", "timeClose": "01:00" },
                { "timeOpen": "12:00", "timeClose": "03:00" }
            ]
        }
    },
    "status": true,
    "specific_timings": true,
    ]
};
```

I want to turn all the timingsEnabled from true to false at once.

**what I have tried**

I found a similar thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30098942/javascript-set-all-values-in-array-of-object/30099117)

The following snippet is what was in the post and it works.. I tried implementing it in my own code and it does not seem to work, I shall include a snippet with my own code below.

```js
array1 = [{
    name : "users",
    checked : true
  }, {
    name : "active users",
    checked : false
  }, {
    name : "completions",
    checked : false
  }]

  console.log(array1.map(function(x) { 
    x.checked = true; 
    return x
  }));
```

```js
car = {
"car_id": "325SDGSD-GSH4GRWW-DH534R",
"Name": "suzuki",
"desc": "compact machine to get your from point A to B",
"engineSerial": "305-6467-3674",
"Country": "Netherlands",
"Province": "George",
"City": "Charlie",
"branch_timings": {
    "Monday": {
        "doorsOpen": true,
        "timings": [
            { "timeOpen": "00:01", "timeClose": "01:00" },
            { "timeOpen": "12:00", "timeClose": "00:00" }
        ]
    },
    "Tuesday": {
        "doorsOpen": true,
        "timings": [
            { "timeOpen": "00:01", "timeClose": "01:00" },
            { "timeOpen": "12:00", "timeClose": "00:00" }
        ]
    },
    "Wednesday": {
        "doorsOpen": true,
        "timings": [
            { "timeOpen": "00:01", "timeClose": "01:00" },
            { "timeOpen": "12:00", "timeClose": "00:00" }
        ]
    },
    "Thursday": {
        "doorsOpen": true,
        "timings": [
            { "timeOpen": "00:01", "timeClose": "01:00" },
            { "timeOpen": "12:00", "timeClose": "00:00" }
        ]
    },
    "Friday": {
        "doorsOpen": true,
        "timings": [
            { "timeOpen": "00:01", "timeClose": "01:00" },
            { "timeOpen": "12:00", "timeClose": "00:00" }
        ]
    },
    "Saturday": {
        "doorsOpen": true,
        "timings": [
            { "timeOpen": "00:01", "timeClose": "01:00" },
            { "timeOpen": "12:00", "timeClose": "00:00" }
        ]
    },
    "Sunday": {
        "doorsOpen": true,
        "timings": [
            { "timeOpen": "00:01", "timeClose": "01:00" },
            { "timeOpen": "12:00", "timeClose": "03:00" }
        ]
    }
},
"status": true,
"specific_timings": true,
]
};
```

As you can see it gives the error that locations.map is not a function. I would appreciate some feedback on what I am doing wrong or how I can fix this

Comment: Hey, please do not completely change the title, body and topic of your question after you already received answers on it! This is *really bad style* as it leaves answers hanging in here that seem completely unrelated to the question. Please undo you latest changes and revert to the original question. After that start the current topic as a new question, but only *after* thoroughly researching that this *is* a new question and has not been asked before. The answer to the "new" question can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34087850/2610061

Comment: I've rolled the question back; it is inappropriate and against Stack Overflow policy to change questions after getting answers. Ask a new question or read the answers on the duplicate provided by @cars10m.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
for (var key in locations.branch_timings) {
        locations.branch_timings[key].timingsEnabled = false;
}
```

Comment: how would I console.log this as logging it before a for loop doesn't work if I'm not wrong

Comment: Would this be possible with a while loop as well? And what would I need to console.log after that loop? I'm fairly new to JS and I'm having trouble understanding it, could you please explain?

Comment: @SystematicallyWrongHa Be clear, I do not understand what result you are looking for

Comment: I'm asking if your approach could be edited in such a way that instead of using the for loop or forEach, we use a while loop and also you asked me to console.log it after the for, what exactly would I be console.logging?

Comment: I have a restriction, I was able to do this before with forEach but I was asked to do it without for loop or forEach that is why I am unable to solve it, I do not understand how to incorporate a while loop into it

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to accomplish this:

```
Object.values(locations.branch_timings).forEach(day => day.timingsEnabled = false)
```

Answer (score 1):

@Baruch Mashasha already nailed it already with his answer. But here is another way of doing it:

```
Object.values(locations.branch_timings).forEach(o=>
  o.timingsEnabled && (o.timingsEnabled=false));
```

In my version I check whether the property `timingsEnabled` actually exists before setting it.

```js
locations = {
    "location_id": "325SDGSD-GSH4GRWW-DH534R",
    "Name": "Earth",
    "Address": "Milky Way Galaxy, Alpha Quadrant, near Mars",
    "Phone": "111-111-111",
    "AddressContinue": null,
    "Zip": "73463",
    "Locality": "Testing location name",
    "Country": "Netherlands",
    "Province": "George",
    "City": "Charlie",
    "Latitude": "22.22222",
    "Longitude": "11.111111",
    "enable_store_timings": true,
    "branch_timings": {
        "Monday": {
            "timingsEnabled": true,
            "timings": [
                { "timeOpen": "00:01", "timeClose": "01:00" },
                { "timeOpen": "12:00", "timeClose": "00:00" }
            ]
        },
        "Tuesday": {
            "timingsEnabled": true,
            "timings": [
                { "timeOpen": "00:01", "timeClose": "01:00" },
                { "timeOpen": "12:00", "timeClose": "00:00" }
            ]
        },
        "Wednesday": {
            "timingsEnabled": true,
            "timings": [
                { "timeOpen": "00:01", "timeClose": "01:00" },
                { "timeOpen": "12:00", "timeClose": "00:00" }
            ]
        },
        "Thursday": {
            "timingsEnabled": true,
            "timings": [
                { "timeOpen": "00:01", "timeClose": "01:00" },
                { "timeOpen": "12:00", "timeClose": "00:00" }
            ]
        },
        "Friday": {
            "timingsEnabled": true,
            "timings": [
                { "timeOpen": "00:01", "timeClose": "01:00" },
                { "timeOpen": "12:00", "timeClose": "00:00" }
            ]
        },
        "Saturday": {
            "timingsEnabled": true,
            "timings": [
                { "timeOpen": "00:01", "timeClose": "01:00" },
                { "timeOpen": "12:00", "timeClose": "00:00" }
            ]
        },
        "Sunday": {
            "timingsEnabled": true,
            "timings": [
                { "timeOpen": "00:01", "timeClose": "01:00" },
                { "timeOpen": "12:00", "timeClose": "03:00" }
            ]
        }
    },
    "status": true,
    "specific_timings": true,
    "delivery_areas": [
        "Earth Quadrant a",
        "Earth Quadrant b",
        "Earth Quadrant c",
        "Earth Quadrant d",
        "Earth Quadrant e"
    ]
};

Object.values(locations.branch_timings).forEach(o=>o.timingsEnabled && (o.timingsEnabled=false));

console.log(locations.branch_timings);
```

Comment: Would this be possible with a while loop as well? for and forEach loops are kind of a no-go for me in this

Comment: With respect to `while`  loops, see @tevemadar's comment above. Can you explain *why* `.forEach` is a "no go" for you?

Answer (score 0):

your locations object is not an array, that's why it does not work.
You want to map on the "branch_timings" property of your locations object, but it's not an array type neither. If you want to use the map() function you have to make this property an array.

Comment: TypeError: locations.branch_timings.map is not a function - its giving the same issue still

Comment: yeah it's because it's "plain" json.

console.log(locations['branch_timings'].map(function(x) { 
x.timingsEnabled = false; 
return x

If it's throwing same error, cast "locations['branch_timings'" as any.

Or write a class (best way)

Comment: your location object is not a typed class object, so your environment says "the locations object has no property called branch_timings"

Comment: your branc_timeings object is also not an array. So you cannot use the map() function here.

Comment: okay thankyou! i'll try doing what you said on my end too

Comment: Check my answer @SystematicallyWrongHa

Answer (score 0):

`branch_timings` is an object, so you could iterate over its keys (`"Monday"`, `"Tuesday"`, etc). One approach to do this is getting the array of those keys using `Object.key()`:

```js
let locations = {
    "location_id": "325SDGSD-GSH4GRWW-DH534R",
    "Name": "Earth",
    "Address": "Milky Way Galaxy, Alpha Quadrant, near Mars",
    "Phone": "111-111-111",
    "AddressContinue": null,
    "Zip": "73463",
    "Locality": "Testing location name",
    "Country": "Netherlands",
    "Province": "George",
    "City": "Charlie",
    "Latitude": "22.22222",
    "Longitude": "11.111111",
    "enable_store_timings": true,
    "branch_timings": {
        "Monday": {
            "timingsEnabled": true,
            "timings": [
                { "timeOpen": "00:01", "timeClose": "01:00" },
                { "timeOpen": "12:00", "timeClose": "00:00" }
            ]
        },
        "Tuesday": {
            "timingsEnabled": true,
            "timings": [
                { "timeOpen": "00:01", "timeClose": "01:00" },
                { "timeOpen": "12:00", "timeClose": "00:00" }
            ]
        },
        "Wednesday": {
            "timingsEnabled": true,
            "timings": [
                { "timeOpen": "00:01", "timeClose": "01:00" },
                { "timeOpen": "12:00", "timeClose": "00:00" }
            ]
        },
        "Thursday": {
            "timingsEnabled": true,
            "timings": [
                { "timeOpen": "00:01", "timeClose": "01:00" },
                { "timeOpen": "12:00", "timeClose": "00:00" }
            ]
        },
        "Friday": {
            "timingsEnabled": true,
            "timings": [
                { "timeOpen": "00:01", "timeClose": "01:00" },
                { "timeOpen": "12:00", "timeClose": "00:00" }
            ]
        },
        "Saturday": {
            "timingsEnabled": true,
            "timings": [
                { "timeOpen": "00:01", "timeClose": "01:00" },
                { "timeOpen": "12:00", "timeClose": "00:00" }
            ]
        },
        "Sunday": {
            "timingsEnabled": true,
            "timings": [
                { "timeOpen": "00:01", "timeClose": "01:00" },
                { "timeOpen": "12:00", "timeClose": "03:00" }
            ]
        }
    },
    "status": true,
    "specific_timings": true,
    "delivery_areas": [
        "Earth Quadrant a",
        "Earth Quadrant b",
        "Earth Quadrant c",
        "Earth Quadrant d",
        "Earth Quadrant e"
    ]
};

let branch_timings=locations.branch_timings;
for(let key of Object.keys(branch_timings)){
  branch_timings[key].timingsEnabled=false;
}

console.log(locations);
```

Comment: would there be a way to do this without using the for loop? would this be possible with a while loop as well? if so how would we go about using key in that

Comment: With a `while` loop you would need to use indexes, something like `let keys=Object.keys(...); let i=0; while(i<keys.length){let key=keys[i]; ... ; i++;}`. In fact even an indexed `for` loop is more compact than that. On the other hand, mapping does not really work here as the intent is not about creating a new array, and that's what `map()` is good at.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com]! We hope you like it here.

You can focus on `locations.branch_timings`, extract it's keys and use them to set the required property to false `forEach` of the keys:

```
//point to branch_timings
let b = locations.branch_timings;

Object.keys(b).forEach(key => !b[key].timingsEnabled || (b[key].timingsEnabled = false));
```

```js
let locations = {
    "location_id": "325SDGSD-GSH4GRWW-DH534R",
    "Name": "Earth",
    "Address": "Milky Way Galaxy, Alpha Quadrant, near Mars",
    "Phone": "111-111-111",
    "AddressContinue": null,
    "Zip": "73463",
    "Locality": "Testing location name",
    "Country": "Netherlands",
    "Province": "George",
    "City": "Charlie",
    "Latitude": "22.22222",
    "Longitude": "11.111111",
    "enable_store_timings": true,
    "branch_timings": {
        "Monday": {
            "timingsEnabled": true,
            "timings": [
                { "timeOpen": "00:01", "timeClose": "01:00" },
                { "timeOpen": "12:00", "timeClose": "00:00" }
            ]
        },
        "Tuesday": {
            "timingsEnabled": true,
            "timings": [
                { "timeOpen": "00:01", "timeClose": "01:00" },
                { "timeOpen": "12:00", "timeClose": "00:00" }
            ]
        },
        "Wednesday": {
            "timingsEnabled": true,
            "timings": [
                { "timeOpen": "00:01", "timeClose": "01:00" },
                { "timeOpen": "12:00", "timeClose": "00:00" }
            ]
        },
        "Thursday": {
            "timingsEnabled": true,
            "timings": [
                { "timeOpen": "00:01", "timeClose": "01:00" },
                { "timeOpen": "12:00", "timeClose": "00:00" }
            ]
        },
        "Friday": {
            "timingsEnabled": true,
            "timings": [
                { "timeOpen": "00:01", "timeClose": "01:00" },
                { "timeOpen": "12:00", "timeClose": "00:00" }
            ]
        },
        "Saturday": {
            "timingsEnabled": true,
            "timings": [
                { "timeOpen": "00:01", "timeClose": "01:00" },
                { "timeOpen": "12:00", "timeClose": "00:00" }
            ]
        },
        "Sunday": {
            "timingsEnabled": true,
            "timings": [
                { "timeOpen": "00:01", "timeClose": "01:00" },
                { "timeOpen": "12:00", "timeClose": "03:00" }
            ]
        }
    },
    "status": true,
    "specific_timings": true,
    "delivery_areas": [
        "Earth Quadrant a",
        "Earth Quadrant b",
        "Earth Quadrant c",
        "Earth Quadrant d",
        "Earth Quadrant e"
    ]
};

//point to branch_timings
let b = locations.branch_timings;

Object.keys(b).forEach(key => !b[key].timingsEnabled || (b[key].timingsEnabled = false));

console.log( locations );
```

Alternatively, you can use a `for of` loop on the values (as opposed to keys) of `locations.branch_timings` as follows:

```
for( let a of Object.values(locations.branch_timings) ) {
    !a.timingsEnabled || (a.timingsEnabled = false);
}
```

```js
let locations = {
    "location_id": "325SDGSD-GSH4GRWW-DH534R",
    "Name": "Earth",
    "Address": "Milky Way Galaxy, Alpha Quadrant, near Mars",
    "Phone": "111-111-111",
    "AddressContinue": null,
    "Zip": "73463",
    "Locality": "Testing location name",
    "Country": "Netherlands",
    "Province": "George",
    "City": "Charlie",
    "Latitude": "22.22222",
    "Longitude": "11.111111",
    "enable_store_timings": true,
    "branch_timings": {
        "Monday": {
            "timingsEnabled": true,
            "timings": [
                { "timeOpen": "00:01", "timeClose": "01:00" },
                { "timeOpen": "12:00", "timeClose": "00:00" }
            ]
        },
        "Tuesday": {
            "timingsEnabled": true,
            "timings": [
                { "timeOpen": "00:01", "timeClose": "01:00" },
                { "timeOpen": "12:00", "timeClose": "00:00" }
            ]
        },
        "Wednesday": {
            "timingsEnabled": true,
            "timings": [
                { "timeOpen": "00:01", "timeClose": "01:00" },
                { "timeOpen": "12:00", "timeClose": "00:00" }
            ]
        },
        "Thursday": {
            "timingsEnabled": true,
            "timings": [
                { "timeOpen": "00:01", "timeClose": "01:00" },
                { "timeOpen": "12:00", "timeClose": "00:00" }
            ]
        },
        "Friday": {
            "timingsEnabled": true,
            "timings": [
                { "timeOpen": "00:01", "timeClose": "01:00" },
                { "timeOpen": "12:00", "timeClose": "00:00" }
            ]
        },
        "Saturday": {
            "timingsEnabled": true,
            "timings": [
                { "timeOpen": "00:01", "timeClose": "01:00" },
                { "timeOpen": "12:00", "timeClose": "00:00" }
            ]
        },
        "Sunday": {
            "timingsEnabled": true,
            "timings": [
                { "timeOpen": "00:01", "timeClose": "01:00" },
                { "timeOpen": "12:00", "timeClose": "03:00" }
            ]
        }
    },
    "status": true,
    "specific_timings": true,
    "delivery_areas": [
        "Earth Quadrant a",
        "Earth Quadrant b",
        "Earth Quadrant c",
        "Earth Quadrant d",
        "Earth Quadrant e"
    ]
};

for( let a of Object.values(locations.branch_timings) ) {
    !a.timingsEnabled || (a.timingsEnabled = false);
}

console.log( locations );
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, would this be possible with a while loop as well? I have a restriction of not using for or forEach

Comment: Yes, of course. I'll update my answer in about an hour.

Comment: sorry for getting back late, I tried googling how to do it but I couldn't find anything. Going to continue looking.

Comment: Did you say `while` loop? I though you said just loop. Why would you want to use a while loop in a case like this, if you really know who while works? ... Did you just change the question on us?